# CkEditor is blank for first time with ajax in MVC 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, asp.net-mvc-5, ckeditor

I am working with MVC 5 and Bootstrap framework. Here I have popup in which I have used CkEditor for managing my content in my application. Popup has a list view in which the saved data from Ckeditor is shown and in another view I am just performing edit and add operation with Ckeditor. Here is my code for generating CKEditor

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.TcBody, new { @class = "form-control", rows = 5, id = "EmailBody", name = "EmailBody" })
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['EmailBody'];
    if (editor) {
      delete CKEDITOR.instances['EmailBody'];;
      //editor.destroy(true);
    }
    CKEDITOR.replace('EmailBody');                     
 </script>
```

I am loading ckeditor.js like this in the View where I am performing Add/Edit.

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Problem here with me is CkEditor is not loading for first time and sometime it loads normally. In my development environment it is working fine but in live application in internet it is not loading CkEditor. If I cancel from Edit View and go back to list view.

Again come back to Edit view the Ckeditor works fine. I tried to destroy the CkEditor and try to replace CkEditor but it works fine. I am switching views through ajax postback. Probably this is because CkEditor loads after some time when the DOM is fully ready. I am not been able to figure out what is the problem and what is the solution too.

Comment: Are you loading this file directly on page? So your `<script>` tag is located in this page code or in the _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: Yes Andrew.. I am adding <script> tag in the view itself.

Comment: Try to move this script loading to layout page. Maybe it will help

Comment: I tried that as well but it is not working

Comment: Are you using bundles?

Comment: Yes but just to load jquery files, Custom Jquery and validation jQuery Files

Comment: Try to create another bundle and load this file from your bundle. Another option is to use CDN link if this file has CDN version uploaded

Comment: tried to create bundle and through CDN as well but the result is same

Comment: is this library ahs to be initialized manually?